# How to pass argument from item in listview to template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

im pretty new to Asp, kendo and javascript. So my apologize if my question is stupid.

i have this code

```
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="portalTemplate">
    <div class="product">
        <a href="@Url.Action(PortalUrl , "Portal")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("../Images/Portal/cs-CZ/")#:ImageName#"          alt="#:ImageName#" style="margin : 4px" />
        </a>
    </div>
</script>

<style>
       .product {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-18 col-md-12">
            @(Html.Kendo().ListView<CS_Shared.MemberShipDataTypes.PortalResult>()
                  .Name("portalListView")
                  .TagName("div")
                  .ClientTemplateId("portalTemplate")
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:650px;" })
                  .DataSource(dataSource => {
                      dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetPortalData", "Portal"));
                  })
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Problem is quite clear, I need to pass the information about Portal URL in portalTemplate. Replace PortalUrl with variable, like "#:PortalUrl#". Any help?

Comment: Any news on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this template:

```
<a href="#:replaceUrl('@Url.Action("PortalUrl", "Portal")', PortalUrl) #">
```

The template will result in something like:

```
<a href="#:replaceUrl('Portal/PortalUrl', PortalUrl) #">
```

Then declare the function in the global scope:

```
<script>
function replaceUrl(original_url, replacement) {
    return original_url.replace('PortalUrl', replacement);
}
</script>
```